# force applied in x axis using UIAccelerometer

Tags: iphone

I want to determine the force applied or the speed at which the iphone is moved in x axis using UIAccelerometer.

Answer (score 0):

So ?  Check out the http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccelerometerDelegate_Protocol/UIAccelerometerDelegate/UIAccelerometerDelegate.html This shows you what you need to know.